# Eyeglasses lens showing frame reflections

Tags: materials

[image: eyeglasses]

So I've been trying to make a pair of glasses for my character. However, when I attempted to test out the glasses, I found out that the lens were showing reflections of the frame of the eyeglases.
The picture above is showing the nodes I've used.
[image: model]

Furthermore, the eye makeup is not showing through the lens.
[image: no eye makeup]

What can I do to avert this issue?

https://pasteall.org/media/1/c/1c7f0e2a0e53c1159044a3e2078bddda.blend

Comment: Suspect shade smooth in this instance.  Support loops around the edges may fix this.

Comment: But fwiw some very very slight effect like this is photorealistic

Comment: could you please share your glasses object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure. I'll add it soon

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/media/1/c/1c7f0e2a0e53c1159044a3e2078bddda.blend

Comment: I notice your glasses lenses are simple planes.  A solidify modifier to give the glass thickness might help.